# align="center" workaround

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a template that I didn't create myself for a Joomla based website. I am trying to center a jquery menu and have spent hours going through all of the code and css and can't seem to find out how to do it! so,  I've decided to create a little work around. I made a blank png image and put it to the left of the menu and have made it's width equal to the offset I want. This little hack works fine except that not all screens are the same size and so it isn't actually centered on most screens. I was wondering if anyone knew a dynamic way to calculate what exactly the center is so I can change the width of the blank png dynamically to that when the page loads?

Hope that makes sense and any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: why dont you inspect the css with firebug or chrome and then add a css record that changes the element you want?

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS For Centering an Element:

```
#elementID {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I read in places that the element needs to have the CSS `width` property set for this to take effect, but I have found that this is not always the case.

Answer (score 1):

Either:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Or

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Will work. :)

Answer (score 1):

place it in div with a div wrapper i.e.

```
<div id = "mainWrapper">

   <div id = "leftColumn"></div><!-- end leftColumn -->

   <div id = "centerColumn">
     <!-- Put you menu item in here -->
   </div><!-- end centerColumn -->

   <div id = "rightColumn"></div><!-- end rightColumn -->

</div><!-- end main wrapper -->
```

css as follows 
     #mainWrapper
     {
        float:left;
        width:100%;
     }
     #leftColumn
     {
       float:left;
       width:25%;
     }
     #centerColumn
     {
       float:left;
       width:50%;
     }
     #rightColumn
     {
       float:left;
       width:25%;
     }

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to center an element using CSS is with `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;`.

In addition, the element needs to be displayed as a block and have a fixed width.

So your CSS would look something like this:

```
.myelement {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    display:block;
    width:100px;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

while

```
margin:0 auto
```

works with the main container of the site (the parent of this container is the body), it get a little wonky  when you have it inside containers, like i sounds you do.

try something like this since you know the width:

```
#selector{
    width:500px; /* however wide the element is */
    position:absolute;
    top:20px; /* This is whatever you want */
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:-250px; /* this is half of the width */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try inspecting the css with firebug or chrome and then add a css record that changes the element you want

Comment: @Phil, no this is an answer.   That could be the issue.